# How to store a value for later use?

Tags: java

I am a new user and I have a "noob" question. We are being taught Java in school and I have a question about one of our activities. One requirement is to take in student info (such as course) and convert them to a single letter (I assume use .charAt??) and then later on count how many students are enrolled into that course. I have the student info down here:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class CourseTallier 
{
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    String student = inputStudInfo();
}
public static String inputStudInfo () 
{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int limit = 0, idnum = 0;
    String college = "";
    System.out.println("Please input a valid ID number:");
    idnum = Integer.parseInt(kbd.nextLine());
    if (idnum == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using this program.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while (idnum < limit) {
        System.out.println("Invalid ID number. Please enter a positive integer:");
        idnum = Integer.parseInt(kbd.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid course (BLIS, BSCS, BSIS, or BSIT");
    college = kbd.nextLine();
    while(!college.equalsIgnoreCase("BLIS") && !college.equalsIgnoreCase("BSCS") && !college.equalsIgnoreCase("BSIS") && !college.equalsIgnoreCase("BSIT"))
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid course. Please enter either BLIS, BSCS, BSIS, or BSIT");
        college = kbd.nextLine();
    }
    return college;
}
public static Character convertCourse (String college) 
{
}
```

and as you can see I am stuck at the "Convert Course" method (modular is required). I was wondering how would I convert something like "BLIS" to a single character "L" and then create another method that counts the number of how many students are enrolled in that course.

I am not asking for someone to complete this program for me cause that would be cheating. I am simply asking someone for a shove in the right direction. Your help is very much appreciated.

Edit: As asked here are the exact requirements:
[Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiCBS.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to single character? You can save the whole word.

Comment: The requirement you described is unclear.  Share the exact wording from the problem description if possible.

Comment: @DevendraRanjanTiwari No idea. It was just part of the question/problem given to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the storing for future values, do you know what instance variables are? Unless I misunderstood the question, it seems like it would make sense to make four (static) instance variables that hold the count of users enrolled in each course.

Comment: If you know how arrays work, it would probably be easier to just make a single array.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the .charAt method or use the "switch" statement.
the problem with the charAt method is that you probably can't find different letters for each course using the same indexed letter.(which will bring you to the switch statement again)

To count the number of student enrolled in that course you should have a count variable and increase it every time you convert a course into a single char.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take each letter from the string, here's the way:

```
    String str = "BLIS";
    String strArray[] = str.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(strArray[i]);
    }
```

If you want to map the Course String to individual Characters, below is the way:

```
    Map<String, Character> courseMap = new HashMap<String, Character>();
    courseMap.put("BLIS", 'L');
    courseMap.put("BSCS", 'C');
    courseMap.put("BSIS", 'S');
    courseMap.put("BSIT", 'T');

    for(String courseStr: courseMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(courseStr + " > " + courseMap.get(courseStr));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a switch statement

```
switch(college)
    {
        case "BLIS":
           return("a");
    }
```

Not sure if thats really what your meant to be doing, if your meant to store student data then a Map implementing datastructure would be the go

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you need to make your code more modular. How about dividing it into sections,like, getting user input, validating user input, storing user input.

Well to store the user data, you can use something like a HashMap. Keep course as key (eg BLIS) and no of students as value. In start intialize it with 0.

```
Map<String, Integer> studentCourseHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
studentCourseHashMap.put("BLIS", 0);
```

So, every time a user enrolls for the particular course all you need to do is to find the course and increment it by 1. So, for example if a student enrolled for BLIS course. then,

```
if(studentCourseHashMap.containsKey("BLIS")){
//Checking if BLIS course is available
    Integer noOfStudents = studentCourseHashMap.get("BLIS");
//Increment no of students for each enrollment
    noOfStudents++;
//Saving the updated value in hashmap
    studentCourseHashMap.put("BLIS", noOfStudents);
}
```

Hope this will help, mention your doubts in comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

why not use a counter for each course and increment it whenever the user enters it.

```
switch(college)
case BLIS:
    blisCounter+=1;
break;
case BSCS:
    bscsCounter+=1;
break; 
case BSIS:
    bsisCounter+=1;
break;
case BSIT:
    bsitCounter+=1;
break;
```